# Flutter: Best way to store JWT access token and refresh token

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, mobile, jwt

I'm coming from a JS background and when working with JWT I always store access tokens as a cookie and refresh tokens also as a cookie but with the `httpOnly` flag. Is there a method in Flutter similar to using `httpOnly` where dart has no access to it the same way JS has no access to `httpOnly`?

I'm looking at:

- **Access token:** save to [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)
- **Refresh token:** save to local db ([Isar](https://isar.dev/))

Is this a correct implementation? I understand saving to a local db doesn't exactly work like `httpOnly` so I'm wondering what you are using.

Comment: Are you developing for mobile or web ?

Comment: @ItzDavi For mobile. I'm just using a JS analogy.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to save the jwt token locally in mobile to be used for other request I would suggest using your shared secure storage link.

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

await storage.write(key: 'jwt', value: token);
```

Another possible solution is using shared preference for data offline persistance but its not all to secure or using Hive with an encryped box [doc](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/advanced/encrypted_box)

Comment: How do you store your refresh tokens? I'm already using `FlutterSecureStorage()` for my access token.

Comment: for tokens secure storage. Shared preferences would be the second choice but its not secure (Docs: this plugin must not be used for storing critical data)

Answer (score 0):

Always use flutter secure storage which's using platform specific secure storage for these type of data.

Learn more here https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage